# Почему функция неверно вычисляет среднее арифметическое

Tags: javascript, math

Функция выводит что угодно, но только не среднеарифметическое:

```js
function arrayAvg(array) {
    var sum = 0;
    var arrLength = array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        sum =+ array[i];
    }
    var arrAvg = sum / arrLength;
    return arrAvg;
}

var arr333 = [];
arr333 = arr333.concat(67);
arr333 = arr333.concat(85);
arr333 = arr333.concat(51);
arr333 = arr333.concat(76);

var avg333 = arrayAvg(arr333);
console.log(avg333);
```

Comment: Поменяйте `sum =+ array[i];` на `sum += array[i];`, и будет вам среднее арифметическое.

Comment: выводит последний элемент деленный на длину массива: в данном случае `76/4` === `19`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема тут:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        sum +=array[i];
    }
```

Просто ошибся с присвоением.

Answer (score 1):

```
function arrayAvg(array) {
    var sum = 0;
    var arrLength = array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        sum += +array[i];
    }
    var arrAvg = sum / arrLength;
    return arrAvg;
}

var arr333 = arrayAvg([].concat(67, 85, 51, 76));

console.log(avg333);
```

Comment: Тогда уж можно просто `var arr333 = [67, 85, 51, 76];`. И стоит написать в ответе где у автора вы нашли ошибку и как её исправили.

Comment: @Regent тут больше посыл в сторону concat, если использует его, то не забываем пр опараметры)

Comment: Спасибо за "виражи" синтаксиса! :) Взял на вооружение.

Answer (score 0):

Позвольте предложить тело функции в одну строку, БЕЗ ухудшения читаемости:

```
return arr.reduce((sum, i) => i + sum) / arr.length
```

ВАЖНО. Стрелочная функция НЕ будет работать в IE до 11 версии включительно. Если нужен IE 11, просто замените `(sum, i) => i + sum` на `function(sum, i) {return i + sum}`

Comment: ты параметры местами перепутал: первый параметр - это как раз аккумулятор (sum в твоем случае) а не `i` (index), вместо `i`, кстати, тоже лучше элемент (el, elem), чтобы понятно было

Comment: @Oleg, Стрелочная функция? :D Это называется `Lambda`.

Comment: @Grundy fixed. Мне как раз в данном случае больше `i` нравится. Еще до того, как `i` стал `(index)` было принято именовать переменные по их типу. `i` был `integer` а впоследствии стал просто числовым типом. Написав `i` я какбы подчеркнул что функция, предназначена для работы с числами. Тут вопрос вкуса и восприятия конечно.

Comment: @Oleg, ни разу не видел, чтобы `i` обозначал integer сам по себе, так как это общеупотребимое имя для счетчика в цикле. Да и венгерская нотация не всем нравится.

Comment: @And https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions Вот именно так и принято называть

Comment: @Grundy Как я уже написал, дело вкуса

Comment: @And, из какого источника информация? В принципе лямбдой можно назвать любое функциональное выражение

Comment: @Grundy Если не ошибаюсь, был язык, в котором тип переменной задавался ее именем. Но не помню уже что за язык, давненько дело было

Comment: @Oleg, не уверен за язык, но такая [нотация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), когда тип указывался в имени переменной, часто использовалась микрософтом в коде на c/c++: `n, i` `int` `целочисленная переменная` `nSize, iSize`